# my screengrab is a different pixel size in photoshop to the browser

Tags: images, resolution, adobe-photoshop, pixels

[image]

[image]

I am having trouble understanding why when I inspect an element in my browser (viewing at 100%) it gives me a pixel size which is different to the screengrab opened in photoshop. As you can see from the image attached.
What is going on? In the attached you can see the browser tooltip info versus the photoshop, and they differ. If viewed at 100% in the browser surely they should be the same. A pixel is a pixel isn't it? 
Incidentally my screen resolution  is 1920 x 1200 and a screengrab opened in photoshop is exactly that. So is my browser lying?

http://postimg.org/image/4l5f1gidn/
If I screengrab this image at 100% and open it in Photoshop, it says it is 350 x 350px which is an additional 75%. I cannot account for this.

Comment: This is happening in both chrome and firefox, with exactly the same results. So it doesn't seem likely it is the browser.

Comment: Can you share the URL that contains the image?

Comment: no its a localhost...

Comment: @DavidPostill I have just done the same on the bbc website with the same results, btw

Comment: I am on windows 10 also

Comment: Cannot repro. Windows 7 Firefox <f12> layout says that image is 84 x 24. When I snapshot with screenshot captor it gives me the same size image.

Comment: Is that the dimensions for the BBC element?

Comment: Yes. As rendered in my browser. https://i.imgur.com/NAMQI1y.png

Comment: I was on the news page. The home page is a little different. The image is padded and is an anchor. I cannot select just the image. It is the same size though 84 x 24. https://i.imgur.com/h2zwEP7.png

Comment: Ok, that is the logo graphic, rather than the element in the above case. However, if I view that at 100% and screengrab I get 147 x 42px, the same problem. I really don't understand and I have tonnes of experience with image production

Comment: As I get the correct sizes in screenshot captor I'm tempted to blame photoshop.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fwdsk3f.png 1 pixel out because I have a rollball mouse and it's difficult to be exact.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, you could be right. Do you get 92 x 39.5 for the BBC home page element (rather than the image) above, so I can check that our browsers are concurring?

Comment: 92 x 46 https://i.imgur.com/FOeCO4U.png You seem to be missing the top padding ...

Comment: Your tooltip (chrome / firefox) says something different on that element (rather than computed)?

Comment: Firefox doesn't seem to have a tooltip ...

Comment: @DavidPostill can you screen grab the link in the OP? I have added a new comment which should make clear my problem. Thanks

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/WtaDDAa.png. Note I don't have photoshop to test with.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BCPhI5H.png image properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The reason is that the device being used is a tablet (sort of, a Surface Pro 3). For some reason browsers do not render real pixels, instead 'relative' pixels. Whereas Photoshop calculates the actual pixels of an image.

It is the difference between whats called a "hardware" pixel and a "reference" pixel and this device has a "device-pixel-ratio" of 1.7

https://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio

Comment: Ah. That explains it. You might find this interesting reading http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html and http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis

Comment: Ha, thanks @DavidPostill, I have just read that article, and was going to post them too. I will research into this more but am confident this is the reason for my confusion!

Comment: PPI 72 issue https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13777/71885

Answer (score 1):

The sizes are always relative to the current element - if it is embedded on the next higher level and there the HTML (or the CSS) says 'stretch to fit', everything gets stretched accordingly. There could be multiple levels of that, so it is hard to predict how big it really will be at the end (one of the things that make coding a browser so tough).

Your example seems to be stretched by 75 %.

Comment: "everything gets stretched accordingly". True but I was looking at the computed element size which takes that into account surely?

Comment: But regardless, viewed at 100%, the tooltip should give the pixel size of the rendered element? And that should concur with a screengrab opened in photoshop? I have done this locally and on the bbc, on chrome and firefox and still have the same problem

Comment: @gavin As I get the correct sizes in screenshot captor I'm tempted to blame photoshop.

Comment: @Aganjul can you screen grab the link in the OP? I have added a new comment which should make clear my problem. Thanks

Comment: I did a screen copy (with Windows 10 standard functionality), and it *is* 200 x 200. I am not sure what you *exactly* mean with 'screen grab', but whatever you do, it's a problem on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I should say I am working on a Surface Pro. I think it may have to do with pixels being relative on a 'tablet' device.